# How does the match statement in F# work?

Tags: .net, f#

I'm busy going through the very anaemic walk-through F# project provided by MS in VS 2010 Beta 2, and came across something that needs some explanation:

```
let rec SumList xs =
    match xs with
    | []    -> 0
    | y::ys -> y + SumList ys
```

I assume match is something like a switch in other languages, where an empty list results in a 0 return value, but the second case fascinates me.  Does this tell the 'runtime|interpretor' to evaluate the match argument as *y cons ys*, or rather as 'if the argument is of the form *y cons ys*', recurs with y and ys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may find the discussion here

[Explaining pattern matching vs switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199918/explaining-pattern-matching-vs-switch)

helpful.  I think it's hard to sum up how pattern-matching works, but it's both a control-flow construct (a la switch) as well as a binding construct.

Answer (score 1):

A pattern matching is not like a `switch` statement : `switch` operates on the value of an expression, whereas `match` can also operate on the expression's structure.

Comment: I'd say that makes it like a switch statement that can also operated on the expression's structure...

Comment: Let the value of the 'switch' expression then be the boolean expression 'x is of structure y'.