# Is there anything similar to a Switch Case command in F#?

Tags: c#, f#

I'm practicing F# programming for the first time and I was wondering if there was a command in the language that would emulate the equivalent of a Switch/Case command in C#? I want to make sure to optimize programs so that they don't have to be reset every time to try a different route of the program ***(e.g. Creating three kinds of area calculators and having to reset to try each one out.)***

Edit: I completely forgot about showing the code as an example.
This is what I want to try and edit.

````
```module AreaCalculator =
````

```
printfn "------------------------------"
printfn "Enter 1 to find a rectangle's area."
printfn "Enter 2 to find a circle's area."
printfn "Enter 3 to find a triangle's area."
printfn "Enter here: "
let stringInput = System.Console.ReadLine()

if stringInput = "1" then
  printfn "What is the rectangle's length: "
  let rlString = System.Console.ReadLine()
  printfn "What is the rectangle's width: "
  let rwString = System.Console.ReadLine()

  let rlInt = rlString |> int
  let rwInt = rwString |> int
  let rectArea = rlInt * rwInt

  printfn "The area of the rectangle is: %i" rectArea
elif stringInput = "2" then
  let PI = 3.14156
  printfn "What is the circle's radius: "
  let radiusString = System.Console.ReadLine()
  let radiusInt = radiusString |> float
  let cirlceArea = (radiusInt * radiusInt) * PI

  printfn "The area of the circle is : %f" cirlceArea


elif stringInput = "3" then
  printfn "What is the triangle's base: "
  let baseString = System.Console.ReadLine()
  printfn "What is the triangle's height: "
  let heightString = System.Console.ReadLine()
  
  let baseInt = baseString |> int
  let heightInt = heightString |> int
  let triArea = (heightInt * baseInt)/2

  printfn "The area of the triangle is: %i" triArea

else
  printfn "Please try again"
```

It works fine as is, but I'd like to see if I can rework the program so it doesn't have to be reset every time you want to calculate a different shape's area. I've tried making **stringInput** a mutable variable, as I had seen in a presentation, but it just results in an error like this:

**/home/runner/F-Practice-1/main.fs(59,5): error FS0588: The block following this 'let' is unfinished. Every code block is an expression and must have a result. 'let' cannot be the final code element in a block. Consider giving this block an explicit result.**

What can I do to remedy this?

Comment: Pattern matching is similar (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199918/explaining-pattern-matching-vs-switch). I don't understand the use case you described.

Comment: Can you share an example C# code to illustrate what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @TomasPetricek I got it in now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent construct in F# is called `match`:

```
let stringInput = System.Console.ReadLine()
match stringInput with
    | "1" ->
        printfn "What is the rectangle's length: "
        // ...
    | "2" ->
        printfn "What is the circle's radius: "
        // ...
    | "3" ->
        printfn "What is the triangle's base: "
        // ...
    | _ ->
        printfn "Please try again"
```

More details [here](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/match-expression/).

Comment: Thanks a lot, man! This will really help me out.